# How can I use Spring Expression in <http:conduit> tag?

Tags: spring, cxf, spring-cxf

I've configured Spring CXF client conduit using the below code. I want to set name of conduit using Spring Expression, But it does not work and even `getUrlPattern` does not invoke. When I set the name with hard coded string it works properly. 
How can I fix it?

```
<http:conduit  name="#{conduitResolver.getUrlPattern()}">
            ...........
</http:conduit>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$`

```
<http:conduit  name="${conduitResolver.getUrlPattern}">
            ...........
</http:conduit>
```